# jQuery AJAX works on one page but not another on iPhone

Tags: jquery, ios, caching, load

I am using the following code to load mysql data:

```
<div id="station_data" style="width:100%"></div>
```

and

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    loadstation();
});

function loadstation() {
    $("#station_data").load("http://website.co.uk/celebs/loadstation.php");
    setTimeout(loadstation, 1000);
}
```

This works fine on my PC on multiple pages, however when testing on my iPhone and iPad it works on one page, but the exact same code doesn't work on another page. Whilst trying to get it to work I made an exact copy of the working page with a different name and it doesn't work, even though the code is exactly the same.

Could it be something to do with the cache?

I have tried adding a random number at the end of the URL

```
function loadstation() {
    newrnd =  Math.random();
    the_url = "http://website.co.uk/celebs/loadstation.php?s=" + newrnd;
    $("#station_data").load(the_url);
    setTimeout(loadstation, 1000); 
}
```

I have added PHP headers

```
header("Cache-Control: no-cache"); header("Pragma: no-cache");
```

And also tried turning the cache off

```
$.ajaxSetup ({
    // Disable caching of AJAX responses
    cache: false 
});
```

I don't understand why the same code is working on one page but not another? This problem is only on iPhone/iPad.

I have also tried a full ajax get

```
$.ajax( {
    url: "http://website.co.uk/celebs/loadstation.php",
    type: "GET",
    cache: false,
    success: function(html) {
         $("#foo").html(html);
    } 
});    
setTimeout(loadstation, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed the url to just ./loadstation.php and it worked